# What is the best method for resizing images to a fixed height and width while maintaining image ratio?

Tags: css, image-processing, gd

On [my startups site](http://trekeffect.com/home) you'll notice in the featured destinations section that I have destination images that have a fixed height and width set by using CSS.  The problem is that my images do not maintain their proportion, yet I want them at this size and I want them to look good.

How should I resolve this issue?  Should I make sure that all images that are uploaded are cropped at the necessary ratio?  If so, can I do this automatically using PHP so that I don't have to manually do it?

Comment: Looks like a job for the `object-fit` property, but only 1 browser supports it.  http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-object-fit-object-position/

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like it's exactly what I need, but I need something more cross browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImageMagick. There is an ImageMagick class in PHP and you can

1. Scale / re-size your image to fit with the smaller dimension
2. Crop the other one.

The command line utility can do that very well for you, see i.e [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/)

Although you might be looking for an image re-targeting algorithm, such as [seam carving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving). Don't know if there is an implementation usable in PHP, but Java

Answer (score 0):

try to set one of size property (width OR height) to 100% iif you put the image in an img tag.

if you set the image as a background of a div, you can also specify its width & height with 'background-size' css property